# When are commited changes visible to other transactions?

Tags: oracle11g, transactions, commit

A transaction in an Oracle db makes changes in the db, and the changes are committed. Is it possible that other transactions see the performed changes only after several seconds, not immediately?

**Background:**
We have an application that performs db changes, commits them, and THEN (immediately) it reads the changed data back from the database. However, sometimes it happens that it finds no changes. When the same read is repeated later (by executing the same select manually from SQL Developer), the changed data are returned correctly. The db is standalone, not clustered.

The application does not communicate with the database directly, that would be easy, several layers (including MQ messaging) are involved. We've already eliminated other potential causes of the behaviour (like incorrect parameters, caching etc.). Now I'd like to eliminate an unexpected behaviour of the Oracle db as the cause.

**Edit:**
At first, I'd like to emphasize that I'm NOT asking whether uncommited changes can be visible to other sessions.
At second, the Oracle COMMIT statement has several modifiers, like WRITE BATCH or NOWAIT. I don't know whether these modifiers can have any influence on the answer to my questions, but we are not using them anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your sessions are all using a read committed isolation level, changes would be visible to any query that starts after the data was committed.  It was possible in early versions of RAC to have a small delay between when a change was committed on one node and when it was visible on another node but that has been eliminated for a while and you're not using RAC so that's presumably not it.

If your transactions are using the serializable isolation level and the insert happens in a different session than the select, the change would only be visible to other sessions whose transactions began after the change was committed.  If sessions A & B both start serializable transactions at time 0, A inserts a row at time 1, and B queries the data at time 2, B would see the state of the data at time 0 and wouldn't see the data that was inserted at time 1 until after it committed its transaction.  Note that this would only apply if the two statements are in different sessions-- session A would see the row because it was inserted in A's transaction.

Barring an isolation level issue, I would expect that the `SELECT` wasn't actually running after the `INSERT` committed.

Comment: In my case, the transaction B starts really after A commits, so the isolation levels should have no influence on this. You're writing that nowadays there should be almost no delay between the commit and the visibility of changes to other subsequent transactions. Does the db ensure that the commit is not finished before the changes are made visible to any subsequent transaction? Or, have you an idea how long the delay can be - milliseconds? seconds?

Comment: Your post is tagged for 11g so I assume we're talking about at least 11.1.0.x.  Given that, there should be 0 lag between when a commit completes and when the data is visible to other transactions (assuming the transaction starts after the commit or the transaction isolation level is read committed).  It was possible for there to be a lag in propagating data between nodes in, say, an Oracle 9.2 RAC cluster.  But not in your version of Oracle and not in your single node configuration.